# Set Excel WorkSheet cell.Value from null to empty string C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop

I'm trying to set Excel Worksheet cell.Value from null to Empty string using the below C# code :

```
Excel.Workbook s_workbook = sApp.Workbooks.Open(s_file);
Excel._Worksheet s_ws = s_workbook.Worksheets[1];
if(s_ws.Cells[17][1].value == null) s_ws.Cells[17][1].value = ""; 
string test = s_ws.Cells[17][1].Value.ToString()
```

But when I do this it seems that the cell value is still null as I get the below error pointing to the last line in my above code:

```
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
```

I wonder how I can set the value of `s_ws.Cells[17][1].Value` from null to empty string?

Comment: What lib do you use?

Comment: @IvanKhorin `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

Comment: Oh, no, thanks, no more Interop in my life... but why not to perform null check instead of modifying the file? `s_ws.Cells[17][1].Value?.ToString();`